# minimum libraries required to run ROS

Tags: ros, embedded, ros-kinetic, roscore, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm preparing to enable ROS on my own embedded developing ARM board.

The board runs a customized version of Linux (not Ubuntu or other distros), with limited number of thirdparty libraries cross-compiled and supported.

The ROS prepared to run on this board only needs to support basic node creation, message subscription/publish. What's the minumum libraries/modules required for this?

Do I need to run ROScore on this board? Or just roscpp client library is enough?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336747/minimum-libraries-required-to-run-ros/) by [uestclx](https://answers.ros.org/users/48749/uestclx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need only ros cpp but this use may other libraries

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/melodic-devel/clients/roscpp/package.xml

If you use yocto there is something already available from BMW

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uestclx](https://answers.ros.org/users/48749/uestclx/) on 2019-11-07**:
Then I don't understand why roscore is not needed? From roscore's wiki page, it says "roscore is a collection of nodes and programs that are pre-requisites of a ROS-based system. You must have a roscore running in order for ROS nodes to communicate." So if there's no roscore running on my board, how can my board communicate with other nodes within the same network? Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-11-07**:
If one ros core / ros master is running inside of you Roboter then it is enough. If you bord only realize on nativ  ros anabled device then you do not need the master. If you full robot is running an you board then you do need a ros core / ros master

**Comment by [uestclx](https://answers.ros.org/users/48749/uestclx/) on 2019-11-08**:
Got it. That clears a lot of things. Thanks a lot.